# Changing background color on jqgrid subgrid title bar but all title bars are changing colors

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, subgrid

I have a project that involves 3 sub grids and I am trying to change the color of at the very least the last sub grid title bar. I have tried many different code combinations but have yet to get just one title bar to be different. I am able to change the color on all the title bars on all the sub grids.

I have looked on the internet for awhile but have not found a good way of doing a simple thing.

Here is last 3 attempts that I have tried:

```
afterInsertRow: function (id, currentData, jsondata) {                            
        if ($("#" + "PT").getGridParam('lastpage') === 0) {
          CMN.OkDialog("No Data To Display");
          }
          else {
            var HeaderFontColor = "black";
            var HeaderBackgroundColor = "brown";      
            //Ths does not produce the results I am looking
            //for this is all the title bars
            $('.ui-jqgrid-titlebar').each(function () {                                    
               this.style.color = HeaderFontColor;
               this.style.background = HeaderBackgroundColor;
             });
           }
         },



    afterInsertRow: function (id, currentData, jsondata) {                            
       if ($("#" + "PT").getGridParam('lastpage') === 0) {
        CMN.OkDialog("No Data To Display");
      }
      else {
        var HeaderFontColor = "black";
        var HeaderBackgroundColor = "brown";      
        //Ths does not produce the results I am looking 
        //for this is also does all the title bars
        $("#" + "PT").jqgrid(
             $('.ui-jqgrid-titlebar').each(function () {                                    
             this.style.color = HeaderFontColor;
             this.style.background = HeaderBackgroundColor;
             }));
        }
    },




    afterInsertRow: function (id, currentData, jsondata) {                            
       if ($("#" + "PT").getGridParam('lastpage') === 0) {
         CMN.OkDialog("No Data To Display");
       }
       else {
         var HeaderFontColor = "black";
         var HeaderBackgroundColor = "brown";      
        //This does not produce the results I am looking for 
        //this does not change any title bars. 
         $("#" + "PT").jqgrid(
         $('.ui-jqgrid-titlebar').last(function () {                                    
           this.style.color = HeaderFontColor;
           this.style.background = HeaderBackgroundColor;
         }));
       }
     },
```

Hopefully someone can help me get at least one of the sub grid's title bar to be different if not all.

Comment: I do not think that afterInserRow is a good choise. Maybe you can use subGrisRowExpanded and here you can change the bacground collor of the subGrid since you know its id like this: `$(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar", "#subgridId").css(....)`

Comment: I know the subgrid "#PT" when I try using $(".ui-jqgridid-titlebar","#"+"PT").css(background, "brown"); Nothing happens. I  thought could just replace  $('.ui-jqgrid-titlebar').last(function () {                                    
           this.style.color = HeaderFontColor;
           this.style.background = HeaderBackgroundColor;
         }